# Custom writer/reader in upickle no longer works after upgrade to 0.7.1

Tags: scala, upickle

I have my own custom DateTime class for which I wrote the following custom writer and reader:

```
val dtWriter = Writer[DateTime]{
    case t => Js.Str(format(t))
}
val dtReader = Reader[DateTime]{
    case Js.Str(time) =>
        try {
            parse(time)
        }
        catch {
            case _: Exception =>
                SDateTime(0)
        }
}
```

However, I tried to upgrade my package version from 0.4.4 to 0.7.1 and this code no longer compiles giving me the following errors:

> Error:(7, 8) object Js is not a member of package upickle
>
> import upickle.Js
>
> Error:(112, 23) object Writer does not take type parameters.
>
> val dtWriter = Writer[DateTime]{

How should this be rewritten in the latest version of upickle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based just on reading http://www.lihaoyi.com/upickle/#CustomPicklers:

```
val dtRW = readwriter[String].bimap[DateTime](
  t => format(t), // also `format _` or just `format` should work
  time =>
    try {
        parse(time)
    }
    catch {
        case _: Exception =>
            SDateTime(0)
    }
)
```